# Javascript `this` vs Python `self` Constructors

Tags: javascript, python, object, constructor

Javascript Constructor + create objects example

```
//Constructor
function Course(title,instructor,level,published,views){
    this.title = title;
    this.instructor = instructor;
    this.level = level;
    this.published = published;
    this.views = views;
    this.updateViews = function() {
        return ++this.views;
    }
}

//Create Objects
var a = new Course("A title", "A instructor", 1, true, 0);
var b = new Course("B title", "B instructor", 1, true, 123456);

//Log out objects properties and methods
console.log(a.title);  // "A Title"
console.log(b.updateViews()); // "123457"
```

what is the python equivalent of this? *(Constructor function / or class + create object instances + log out properties & methods?)*

Is there a difference between `self` from python and `this` from Javascript?

Comment: Pretty much, no difference. Though in python, `self` is by convention, and you can call it anything you want. Also, you have to include it as the first parameter to your constructor, whereas JS "just instinctively knows" what `this` is

Comment: Have you consulted the [Python documentation on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)?

Comment: Your question title has the terms switched

Comment: whoops didn';t realize that will swap

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a python translation:

```
class Course:
    def __init__(self, title, instructor, level, published, views):
        self.title = title
        self.instructor = instructor
        self.level = level
        self.published = published
        self.views = views

    def update_views(self):
        self.views += 1
        return self.views
```

You must declare a class, then initialize *an instance of that class* as follows:

```
course = Course("title","instructor","level","published",0)
```

Some notable differences are that `self` is not implicitly available but is actually a required parameter to all methods of the class. However, you should consult  [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)  on python classes for more information.

### Edit

As of [`python3.7`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html), I feel obligated to show that newly introduced [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-dataclasses) are another (and increasingly common) way of writing simple classes like this.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Course:
     title: str 
     instructor: str 
     level: str 
     published: bool
     views: int 

     def update_views(self) -> int:
         self.views += 1
         return self.views
```

Comment: So in python you have to define the properties / method seperately (with `def`) inside of a class?

Comment: @Kagerjay huh? No, fundamentally Python and Javascript have different OOP models. Javascript uses prototype-based inheritance, whereas Python uses class-based inheritance. I believe classes were introducced in ECM6. Note, you *can* dynamically add function properties to an instance in Python in the constructor, but they won't be inherited.

Comment: well I'm going have to do some more reading thanks for the info :)

Comment: @modesitt could you clarify my answer I posted below, I cannot figure out how to access the method / print out result here

Comment: @Kagerjay sure I will. Give me a minute.

Answer (score 1):

There was some errors on the python solution fixed it now

```
#Constructors
class Course:

    def __init__(self,title,instructor,level,published,views):

        self.propTitle = title
        self.propInstructor = instructor
        self.propLevel = level
        self.propPublished = published
        self.propViews = views

    def update_views(self):
        self.propViews += 1
        return self.propViews

# Create objects
courseA = Course("A title", "A instructor", 1, True, 0)
courseB = Course("B title", "B instructor", 1, True, 123456)

# Print object property and use object method
print(courseA.propTitle)
print(courseB.update_views())
```

Result print out

> A title
>
> 123457

Using `print(courseB.update_views)` outputs this though,`<bound method Course.update_views of <__main__.Course object at 0x7f9f79978908>>` , use `print(courseB.update_views())`

Comment: @Igor is right. You must call the method. It is not a computer property.

Comment: okay thanks i fixed it now, I named everything `prop` prefix so its clear to me which values are arguments and which are not